# Get a Bicep reference to the private IP allocated to an 'auto-generated' NIC on a Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am deploying a [Static Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/) but only want to expose it to my private network so I can funnel traffic through another resource. I'm using a [private endpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) to do this and deploying with Bicep scripts.

When you deploy a private endpoint, it auto-creates a virtual NIC using addresses from the subnet you specify for the staging and primary websites. You can pass in `customNetworkInterfaceName` to specify the naming of the NIC but that is about all the control you have over its creation.

The NIC has the eventual private IP addresses I need however I can't seem to get a reliable reference to the NIC card.

I've tried using the `existing` keyword using the same hardcoded value in `customNetworkInterfaceName` but it resolves before the NIC card is created giving a `ResourceNotFound` error.

How do I get the private IPs?